# Find residue with limit $\lim _{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\frac{e^zz}{\sin\left(z\right)}\right)$ without Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

$$\lim _{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\frac{e^zz}{\sin z}\right)=\lim _{z\to 0}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{e^z\:z+e^z}{\sin z}-\frac{ze^z\cos z}{\sin^2 z}\right)\right)$$

Hi, can someone help me calculate the limit?
The solution the test had is using taylor series, but to be honest, I would have never thought of it and always did using the derivative.
for some reason, I cant reach a correct answer without using taylor.
Much help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ... that's why he said "without Taylor".

Comment: is it possibly that it is impossible without taylor? because it is really weird, never had a limit like that. if it really is impossible, I guess taylor is the way, althought I do not like it.

Comment: You just need to find $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\csc^3(z)(1+2z-\cos(2z)-(z+1)\sin(2z))$

Comment: problem is, it probably requires taylor, since limit of $\frac 1 {sin(z)}$ is not defined and such, I dont know how to explain, but without taylor it is impossible then, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas said, the easy way to do this is **with** Taylor.

Without Taylor?

$$
\frac{d^2}{dz^2} f(z) = {\frac {{2{\rm e}^{z}} \left(  \left( \sin \left( z \right) 
 \right) ^{2}z-\sin \left( z \right) \cos \left( z \right) z+ \left( 
\cos \left( z \right)  \right) ^{2}z+ \left( \sin \left( z \right) 
 \right) ^{2}-\sin \left( z \right) \cos \left( z \right)  \right) }{
 \left( \sin \left( z \right)  \right) ^{3}}}
$$
The limit of this as $z \to 0$ is indeterminate of form $0/0$.  Attempt l'Hopital's rule
$$
-{\frac {2\,{{\rm e}^{z}} \left( \cos \left( z \right) z-2\,\sin
 \left( z \right) z-3\,\sin \left( z \right)  \right) }{3\,\sin
 \left( z \right) \cos \left( z \right) }}
$$
This limit at $z=0$ is still indeterminate of form $0/0$.  Do it again
$$
{\frac {2\,{{\rm e}^{z}} \left( 2\,\sin \left( z \right) z-\cos
 \left( z \right) z+3\,\sin \left( z \right)  \right) +2\,{{\rm e}^{z}
} \left( 2\,\cos \left( z \right) z+2\,\sin \left( z \right) +\sin
 \left( z \right) z+2\,\cos \left( z \right)  \right) }{3\, \left( 
\cos \left( z \right)  \right) ^{2}-3\, \left( \sin \left( z \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
Now we can plug in $z=0$ to get the answer
$$
\frac{4}{3}
$$

Comment: oh, I dont think we learnt lhopital at complex, but I guess if I have something like that at test, I will really use it, i dont think there will be a problem.  Thank you very much!! It helped me alot :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, without l'Hospital, just using standard limits we have

$$\frac{d^2}{dz^2} f(z) = \frac {{2{\rm e}^{z}} \left( z\sin^2 z-z\sin z \cos z + z\cos^2 z+ \sin^2 z-\sin z \cos z  \right) }{\sin^3 z}=$$

$$=2e^z \left(\frac {z}{\sin z}+(\cos z - \sin z)\frac {z\cos z - \sin z}{\sin^3 z}\right)$$

with $e^z \to 1$ and $\frac {z}{\sin z}\to 1$, $(\cos z - \sin z)\to 1$ and

$$ \lim _{z\to 0}\frac {z\cos z - \sin z}{\sin^3 z}=-\frac 1 3 $$

indeed using [these results](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1337564/505767) we have

$$\small \frac {z\cos z - \sin z}{\sin^3 z}=\frac {z\cos z-z+z - \sin z}{\sin^3 z}=\frac{z^3}{\sin^3 z}\left(\frac{\cos z-1}{z^2}+\frac{z-\sin z}{z^3}\right)\to 1\cdot \left(-\frac12+\frac16\right)=-\frac13$$

then finally

$$2e^z \left(\frac {z}{\sin z}+(\cos z - \sin z)\frac {z\cos z - \sin z}{\sin^3 z}\right)\to 2\cdot \left(1-\frac13\right)=\frac43$$

Comment: Oh dam, Very good one, it uses lots of thinking skills ( multi and divide z and such ), great ideas, I will learn this carefully. Huge thanks :)

Comment: @LearningToCode Yes! If you are not familiar with Taylor, standard limits can be very useful to obtain simpler expression and often the result directly. You are welcome. Bye